# Concatenate Columns without duplicated values

Tags: sql, sql-server

do you know how can I concatenate these columns without duplicate values, suppose that I have a table with this structure (Result of outer join):

```
ColumnA     ColumnB
--------------------
12345       null
69875       null
null        15648
76582       76582
null        29829
35731       35731
```

The desire output:

```
ColumnC
-------
12345       
69875      
15648       
76582       
29829       
35731
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: That's a `coalesce(ColumnA, ColumnB) as ColumnC` But yes, it should have been easy to discover this on your own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's the best way I could think of

```
DECLARE @ColumnA TABLE (val INT)
INSERT INTO @ColumnA VALUES (12345)
INSERT INTO @ColumnA VALUES (69875)
INSERT INTO @ColumnA VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO @ColumnA VALUES (76582)
INSERT INTO @ColumnA VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO @ColumnA VALUES (35731)

DECLARE @ColumnB TABLE (val INT)
INSERT INTO @ColumnB VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO @ColumnB VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO @ColumnB VALUES (15648)
INSERT INTO @ColumnB VALUES (76582)
INSERT INTO @ColumnB VALUES (29829)
INSERT INTO @ColumnB VALUES (35731)

select
    IIF (colA.val = colB.val, CAST(colA.val AS VARCHAR), ISNULL(CAST(colA.val AS VARCHAR), '') + ISNULL(CAST(colB.val AS VARCHAR), '')) concatenado
from (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) nro, val
    FROM @ColumnA
) colA
JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) nro, val
    FROM @ColumnB
) colB ON colA.nro = colB.nro
```